# Usage of "deadline" and "regarding"

Tags: word-usage

Could someone tell me if that's correct? What I meant to say is that I'd like to know the last day when I could apply for Admission and for the Scholarships at a school (There are 2 different forms, one for the Admissions and another for the Scholarships).

> "Good evening! I would like to know the applications **deadline regarding** the Scholarships and Admissions."

Comment: Could you please tell me the deadlines for scholarship and admissions applications?

Comment: Wow, Johnny! That's exactly what I was trying to write! Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the sentence in its current form:

> I would like to know the application **deadlines regarding** scholarship and admissions.

Assuming there is only one scholarship (as you seem to state), use the singular.

*Deadlines* (plural) is used since there are different deadlines for scholarship and for admissions. If **scholarship and admission** was a single application (idea/entity), the singular **deadline** would be used.

> Please advise what the admission and scholarship deadlines are.

Would be another way of asking the same question.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine, you may also want to check if the deadlines are the same for each scholarship, they could vary sometimes. Good luck!